# load-grunt-config not finding target task

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I want to split a large gruntfile in smaller pieces and came about these articles:
https://github.com/firstandthird/load-grunt-config
http://ericnish.io/blog/how-to-neatly-separate-grunt-files/
However, it seems I'm missing something obvious. When I issue a "grunt testtask" the task is not found. I'm doing something very wrong, obviously, but I don't get it.
Here's the content of the files, stripped down as much as possible:

```
gruntfile.js:
module.exports = function(grunt) {
 var path = require('path');

 require('load-grunt-config')(grunt, {
    configPath: path.join(process.cwd(), 'grunt3'),
        init: true
  });
};

grunt3/testtask.js:
module.exports = {
  copy: {
    main:   
    {
        files: 
        [{
           src:  "test1.txt",
           dest: "test2.txt"
        }]
    }
  }
};

I added an aliases file:
module.exports = {
  'default': [],
  'mytesttask': [
    'testtask'
  ]
};
```

default is found. For mytesttalk I get "testtask not found".
Shouldn't aliases.js do a registerTask either for the filename (testtask) or for "copy" (I also tried using 'copy' as the target task)?
There is a config object named "testtask" according to --config-debug.
What am I missing here?

Thanks.

Addendum: found this very simple and straight-forward article on the same subject which shows how to simplify even further. Just, again, it's not working. The task specified in aliases is not found. e.g. 'mytesttask': [ 'testtask'] -> testtask is not found, although there is a grunt/testtask.js file that contains the task from the original gruntfile. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

With the help of this excellent article http://mattbailey.io/a-beginners-guide-to-grunt-redux.html and one of the authors of that module commenting on github I finally found the flaw in my thinking. The files are not organized by tasks or targets but by grunt modules. So, **you have to name them copy.js (from grunt-contrib-copy), cssmin.js (from grunt-contrib-cssmin), concat.js (from grunt-contrib-concat) und put the various targets in these files**. Not the other way around (as I thought). Maybe that's clear for others from the documentation, it wasn't for me. That article by Matt Bailey is really great as it shows only what is really necessary. The article by Eric Nishio I referenced above is unnecessarily complex as it doesn't account for the aliases file.